# No se muestra mensaje ->with('info', 'Mi mensaje');

Tags: laravel

Tengo definida la siguiente ruta `resource`

```
Route::resource('users', App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class);
```

En mi controlador he intentado esto:

```
return view('users.edit')->with(['user' => $user])->with('info', 'Usuario actualizado con éxito.');


return view('users.edit', compact('user'))->with('info', 'Usuario actualizado con éxito.');


return redirect()->route('users.index')->with(['user' => $user])->with('info', 'Usuario actualizado con éxito.');
```

Y no se muestra el mensaje despues de actualizar la información

En mi layout tengo:

```
@if(session('info'))
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-12 mx-auto">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('info') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Me funciona muy bien utilizando el mismo layout con otra actualización en el mismo controlador.

Comment: El método with funciona distinto para `view` que para `redirect`. Para retornar una vista con un valor de sesión, tienes que setearlo, por ejemplo `session(['info' => 'Usuario actualizado con éxito']);`

Comment: Gracias, intenté agregando tu sugerencia y algo estaba haciendo mal... lo logré colocando en la vista `@if(!empty($info)) <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ $info }}</div> @endif` y en el controlador dejé todo igual.